# determine conditions on the b ’s, if any, in order to guarantee that the linear system is consistent.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm having trouble with the determining conditions that linear systems are consistent on problems like these.. i tried reading the examples of the same kind in the book.. but they dont seem to explain and seem arbitrary and unique.. I know I'm supposed to reduce the whole matrix into reduced row echelon form.. but what is the best way for determining the conditions that it is consistent in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to matrix form:
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -2 & 5 & b_1 \\ 
4 & -5 & 8 & b_2 \\
-3 & 3 & -3 & b_3
\end{bmatrix}
Now we need to achieve row echelon form by performing row operations:

- Row operation $-4R_1+R_2$ and $3R_1+R_3$
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & -2 & 5 & b_1 \\ 
  0 & 3 & -12 & -4b_1+b_2 \\
  0 & -3 & 12 & 3b_1+b_3
  \end{bmatrix}
- Row operation $R_2+R_3$
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & -2 & 5 & b_1 \\ 
  0 & 3 & -12 & -4b_1+b_2 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -b_1+b_2+b_3
  \end{bmatrix}

In order for this matrix system to be consistent, we must have a solution. This only occurs if we do **not** have any rows that are like this:
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & \text{non-zero number}
\end{bmatrix}
because $0x_1+0x_2+0x_3\not=\text{non-zero number}$ for any $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Therefore, from row 3 of the row echelon matrix above, we *must* have
$$-b_1+b_2+b_3=0.$$
Thus, the values of $b_1,b_2,b_3$ must satisfy the condition of $$b_1=b_2+b_3$$

Comment: thanks, that helped some. so how would I answer the question had the answer end up a unique solution for each value of b... without all 0s on the bottom?

Comment: If we get a unique solution, as in the row-echelon matrix's bottom row did not contain all 0s, then we would not have to worry about free variables like $b_1$ (as the solution is *unique*, after all). So, in that case alone, $b_1,b_2,b_3$ should take on numerical values instead of free variables.

Comment: What happens if the (3, 3) entry in the reduced matrix is not zero? Then, how do you show the conditions under which the system is consistent?